# Counting invertible $0$-$1$ matrices that remain invertible under negating the diagonal

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, determinant

> There is an invertible $n×n$ matrix with each entry $0$ or $1$. Now we negate ($x\to 1-x$) the diagonal of the matrix, and it is still invertible. How many such matrices exist for a given $n$?

Can we derive a general formula? If $n=2$ there are $2$ such matrices, if $n=3$ there are $48$. But I have no idea whether a formula exists for higher $n$.

Comment: You can edit your posts over here. This may include context, source of the problem, partial attempts, etc. Everything in dollar signs is maths-typeset (MathJax).

Comment: I suspect that there's no good trick for doing this directly. However, it might be possible to do something with the [total number of singular](http://oeis.org/A046747) $0$-$1$ matrices.

Comment: have you put in any work here?  What about doing this over $\mathbb F_2$ to start?