# How to derive a general formula about the number of n*n nonsingular matrix under one constraint?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields

If there is an n-by-n matrix, each element in the matrix can only be 1 or 0. We assume that an n-by-n matrix is nonsingular, then we do the two's complement at only the diagonal of the matrix. After I do the two's complement at the diagonal, an n-by-n matrix is still nonsingular.
How many numbers of this kind of matrices can be found in an n-by-n matrix??? Can we derive a general formula??
If n=2, I can derive the number of this kind of matrices is 2, n=3, the number of this kind of matrices is 48. But I have no idea whether it exists a general formula when we expand to the n-dimensional matrix.

Comment: Do not [ask](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4127905/357390) the same question twice, even if the first question has no answers. (A bounty would be more appropriate.)

Comment: Also, multiple question marks only make you look juvenile and not to be taken seriously, please avoid doing that, and learn to use MathJax for mathematical expressions. You can [get started here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), and a more complete reference [can be found here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).